# How to Retrieve List Item Using It's Field Name? - SharePoint

Tags: 2010, list, event-receivers

I have two contact lists in my site i.e. Contacts 1 and Contacts 2.

I am creating "item added" event receiver on Contacts 1 that is whenever new entry is made to the Contacts 1 automatically it should be dropped to the Contacts 2.

My logic for copying the entry to the Contacts 2 list is:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    if (properties.List.Title.Equals("Contacts 1"))
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
        {

           SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;


            SPList list = web.Lists["Contacts 2"];
            SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();

            foreach (SPField field in properties.List.Fields)
            {


                item[field.Title] = properties.ListItem[field.Title].ToString();

            }

            item.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

I am still not getting the item copied in the list 'Contacts 2'

What should I do to tackle this error.? Please help.

Comment: Your code will break if the old value is NULL, do a nullcheck on the ListItem[field.Title] before casting it to a string

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Perhaps add "web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;" and then setting it back at the end... Are the lists in the same spweb? If so then you can use properties.Web instead of getting the SPSite.

Comment: @BlueBird AllowUnsafeUpdates only exists in a specific SPSite or SPWeb instance, so no need to set i back :)

Comment: I put the condition ` if(Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem[field.Title])!=null)` but still not getting the record in "Contacts 2" @RobertLindgren

Comment: do if(properties.ListItem[field.Title] != null)

Comment: Sir, did the same but still not working..!! @RobertLindgren